# How to pass variable to total in script

Tags: javascript, rest, paypal

I have the following code to use but i don't know how to pass the [TOTAL] variable which holds the shopping cart total to the total in the paypal script below. Otherwise the buyer will always be able to buy whatever for $1 which obviously is incorrect.

```
<script>
   var $total = document.getElementById("balancePrice");


    paypal.Button.render({




        env: 'production', // Or 'sandbox'

        client: {
              sandbox:    'AYdNDf4q9a-V8p8kcVe885AytuFfmXcwfAn7--tEkgV4UMK7k_QroOJsktMpp6v_Y9r2bKz9OUi6cSFi',
                production: 'AfNogtQ4SAPFsVEZIA_KUbMnuN0uNR3cALoL5PsJHlpuV5tMDxwnty2-Ceu11d82KiqnRmEi_Ykap6fP'
        },

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                           amount: { total: $total, currency: 'GBP' }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

                // The payment is complete!
                // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

Here is the html of the checkout. [BALANCE] is what displays the total cost of the order after shipping etc and what i'd like to be passed to the paypal code.

```
 <div class="divOrderTotal">
          <div class="header">
            <h3 class="checkout-headers">[checkout3_orderTotal]</h3>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="total_div" name="total_div" class="pad10 boxShadow"> 
            <!--START: total_template_noshipping-->
            <div class="totalinstructions pad10 boxShadow">[checkout3_totalinstructions]</div>
            <!--END: total_template_noshipping--> 
            <!--START: total_template-->
            <div class="total_items">[itemCount] Item(s)</div>
            <div class="total_subtotal">[SUBTOTAL]</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--START: DISCOUNTS-->
            <div class="total_discount-detail">[shoppingcart_discount]: <a href="javascript:showDiscountDetails();">(details)</a></div>
            <div class="total_discount">- [DISCOUNT]</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--START: PROMOTIONS-->
            <div id="divDiscountDetails" name="divDiscountDetails" style="display:none;">
              <div class="total_promotion">Promotion Name</div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <!--START: DISPLAY_PROMOS-->
              <div class="total_promotion-name">[promotion_name]</div>
              <div class="button right"><!--START: REMOVE_PROMO--><a href="javascript:removeCoupon('[id]');" class="icon-btn icon-btn-close">Remove</a><!--END: REMOVE_PROMO--></div>
              <!--END: DISPLAY_PROMOS-->
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--END: PROMOTIONS--> 
            <!--END: DISCOUNTS--> 
            <!--START: BUYSAFE-->
            <div class="total_buysafe-logo"><img src="assets/templates/common/images/buysafe.gif" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="total_buysafe">[buysafe_totalbondcost]</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--END: BUYSAFE--> 
            <!--START: HANDLING-->
            <div class="total_handling-item">[handling_itemname]</div>
            <div class="total_handling-price">[handling_price]</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--END: HANDLING-->
            <div class="total_cart-shipping">[shoppingcart_shipping]</div>
            <div class="total_shipping">[SHIPPING]</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="total_cart-taxes">[shoppingcart_taxes]</div>
            <div class="total_taxes">[TAX]</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="total_cart-total">[shoppingcart_total]</div>
            <div class="total_total">[TOTAL]</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--START: GIFTCERTS-->
            <div class="total_cart-giftcerts">[shoppingcart_giftcertificate]: <a href="javascript:showGiftCertDetails();">(details)</a></div>
            <div class="total_giftcerts">-[GIFTCERTS]</div>
            <div id="divGiftCertDetails" name="divGiftCertDetails" style="display:none;">
              <div class="total_giftcerts-details">
                <div class="giftcerts-name">Gift Code</div>
                <div class="giftcerts-amount">Amount</div>
                <div class="giftcerts-balance">Balance</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
              <!--START: GIFTCERTS_DETAILS_ITEMS-->
              <div class="total_giftcerts-details-items">
                <div class="giftcerts-name">[certificate_name]</div>
                <div class="giftcerts-amount">[discount_amount]</div>
                <div class="giftcerts-balance">[discount_balance]</div>
                <div class="button"><a href="javascript:removeCoupon('[id]');" class="icon-btn icon-btn-close">Remove</a></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
              <!--START: GIFTCERTS_DETAILS_ITEMS--> 
            </div>
            <!--END: GIFTCERTS-->
              <div id="divBalance">
          <div class="total_cart-balance">[shoppingcart_balance]</div>
          <div id="balancePrice">[BALANCE]</div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
            <!--START: apply_coupon-->
            <div id="divApplyCoupon">
              <div class="coupon-header">[viewcart_coupon-header]</div>
              <div class="coupon-field">
                <input id="coupon" onchange="clearContent(this);" maxlength="30" size="15" value="" name="coupon_code" class="txtBoxStyle" />
                <input type="button" onclick="applyCoupon(this.form.coupon_code.value);" value="Apply" class="btn" onmouseover="this.className='btn_over'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" />
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <div class="coupon-message">[viewcart_coupon-message]</div>
              <div name="divInvalidCoupon" id="divInvalidCoupon" style="display:[invalidCouponDisplay]; color:#F00;">[viewcart_coupon-invalid]</div>
              <div class="coupon-applied">[divCouponApplied]</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--END: apply_coupon--> 
            <!--END: total_template--> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
```

The following errors happen

```
    ppxo_unhandled_error {stack: "Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textConten…://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3080:13)", errtype: "[object Error]", timestamp: 1516799614450, windowID: "f18cf37d7c", pageID: "2f88e8f682", …}
And this

types.js:119 Uncaught Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
```

When i do the following in the google console i get

```
var a = document.getElementById("balancePrice");
var b = a.textContent;
console.log(b)
```

Results in

```
$5.64
undefined
```

Comment: Its always 1 $ because you have `amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }` in the code.
Could you provide us some HTML so we can see in where all the other data is postet? I mean. somwhere on the page must be a total output.

Comment: Updated with html code. The total output is coming from the variable [BALANCE] which is said to be undefined when i use it

Answer (score 0):

> Updated with html code. The total output is coming from the variable [BALANCE] which is said to be undefined when i use it

I guess that means calling

```
//[...]
amount: { total: '[BALANCE]', currency: 'USD' }
//[...]
```

doesn't do the trick.

---

**Try the following:**

```
 var $total = document.querySelector("#balancePrice");     
 var total = $total.textContent.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, "");

 paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'production', // Or 'sandbox'

    client: {
          sandbox:    'test',
            production: 'test'
    },

    commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

    payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: total, currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

            // The payment is complete!
            // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

I did grabbing for the total-value in the variables above so i don't have to write a long line of code inside the `payment()` function.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply i tried both and updated my OP to reflect this. I'm getting some errors.

Comment: console.log($total); returns that $total is null for some reason

Comment: Updated further my idea is to try and get the value from document.getElementById("balancePrice").textContent; which returns "$5.64". I want to find someway to get rid of the " and $ then in my head it should work.

Comment: Try using `"$5.64".replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');` This should just leave you with the amount.

If that answered your question id appreciate if you would mark it as such

Comment: can i use that on a the variable $total instead?

Comment: No you have to call `$total.textContent.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');`
Ill edit my answer so you can see

Comment: gutted was sure this would work but i'm getting a 
Cannot read property 'textContent' of null on var total.

Comment: sounds odd too me that you get that error. try outputting $total with a `console.log($total);` to see what the queryselector is grabbing.

Comment: When i do the following on google dev tools i get the value i want but not in the code.
var a = document.getElementById("balancePrice");
var b = a.textContent.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
console.log(b)

Comment: ok in your code given above the id your describe is not given. Then try replacing my variable $total with  `$total = document.getElementById("balancePrice")`.

Comment: Still the same issues.

Comment: So console.log($a); returns null

Comment: Uff.. man.. your not making it easy to help you.. can you update your html to match a live example except you replaced certain data that you cant provide with some placeholding data.

Comment: Sorry, what i have up in my OP is what is live. I don't want to provide my client ID's. Just trying to get things fixed as my neck in on the line and i'm panicking.

Comment: I'd love to say that worked but it's still giving me the same problems and. Could be something to do how i'm importing the script? 
I have this <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
Near the top of my page.

Comment: might be. did you try importing it at the end of the page?

Comment: Yea multiple locations all have the same error. I'm going to try and ask paypal for help. Because i'm at a loss. Anyway sorry for frustrating you, really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you. I hope you can solve your problem.

Upvote appreciated for the effort :)